# What is decltype(*it) for BidirectionalIterator?

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, type-inference, decltype

Is `decltype(*it)` the value type of the iterator, or an lvalue reference to that, or something else?

I think it is an lvalue reference, because `*it` is an lvalue, but I'm not sure.

Note: In my case, `it` is a *BidirectionalIterator*, but feel free to answer the general case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`*it` is not necessarily an lvalue. Only forward iterators have that requirement.

Iterators (§24.2.2) are required to have `*it` be a valid expression that returns `iterator_traits<Iterator>::reference` (and other irrelevant things). Nothing else is said about this and `reference` does not have to be  a reference type†.

Input iterators (§24.2.3) are required to have `*it` be a valid expression that returns *something* convertible to the value type.

Forward iterators, however, have the following requirement (§24.2.5 paragraph 1):

> — if `X` is a mutable iterator, `reference` is a reference to `T`; if `X` is a const iterator, `reference` is a reference to `const T`,

(here `T` is the iterator's value type)

This requires `*it` to be a reference, which means it has to be a glvalue (i.e. cannot be a prvalue but can be an xvalue like it is the case with move iterators).

The higher iterator categories do not add any relevant requirements.

---

† `reference` is defined to be the type of `*it` which makes it a bit of a circular definition, but poses no restrictions.

Comment: Do note that regardless what the specification says, it is _established practice_ to write proxy iterators (effectively, iterators for which `*it` is not a reference) that are Forward, Bidirectional, or Random Access Iterators.  For example, `std::vector<bool>::iterator` must be a Random Access iterator, but it's "reference" type is not a reference (it is a proxy that provides access to a particular bit).

Comment: Yes, this is actually one part of the spec that I often voluntarily ignore because it is excessively restrictive. ;)

Comment: You're in good company.  We discussed this at C++Now 2012 and there were (for the most part) two groups of people:  those who knew about this rule but thought it was ignorable, and those who didn't know about this rule, were surprised, and agreed that it was ignorable.  :-)  [There was some discussion about completely rewriting the iterator requirements to better and more clearly express mutable and immutable ranges and to allow for less restrictions on proxy iterators. I don't know what the plan is for that work, or if it will happen, though.]

Answer (score 5):

`*it` is most assuredly not guaranteed to be an lvalue. Input iterators may return an rvalue.